# EF 5 Migrations cannot connect to our database even though it does just fine at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

We have three projects.

- Company.Domain (class library)
- Company.PublicWebsite (MVC3 Web Application)
- Company.InternalWebsite (MVC3 Web Application)

The two website projects have reference to `Company.Domain`.

Our EF 5 `DbContext` lives in `Company.Domain.Data.EntityFramework` and it looks like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using Company.Domain.Data.EntityFramework.Entities;

namespace Company.Domain.Data.EntityFramework.
{
    public class CompanyEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ReportSection> ReportSections { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ReportPage> ReportPages { get; set; }
        // brevity brevity
    }
}
```

We have enabled migrations and successfully used the tool in the past so I'm not sure why we are having issues now. Our migrations configuration lives in `Company.Domain.Data.EntityFramework.Migrations` and looks like this:

```
namespace Company.Domain.Data.EntityFramework.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using Company.Domain.Data.EntityFramework;

    public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CompanyEntities>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            MigrationsDirectory = @"Data\EntityFramework\Migrations";
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(CompanyEntities context)
        {
            // empty at the moment
        }
    }
}
```

We then have an `App.config` file in the root of the `Company.Domain` project and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="CompanyEntities" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=devsql;Initial Catalog=CompanyEntities;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
          <parameter value="v11.0" />
        </parameters>
      </defaultConnectionFactory>
    </entityFramework>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  </configuration>
```

Our database lives on another server on the network. I'm able to connect to it in SQL Server Management Studio and our applications are able to connect at runtime just fine. However, when I try to run `add-migration` or even `update-database` I get the following error:

http://content.screencast.com/users/Chevex/folders/Snagit/media/80fbfd6a-4956-407f-b88f-d5a53a9e5feb/03.21.2013-10.25.png

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. ---> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I've even reverted my changes to the model and then ran `update-database` just to see if it would say 'database is on latest migration' but I still got the above error. I've poured over the connection string in `App.config` over and over. I cannot figure out why migrations won't connect but both of our website projects work just fine at runtime. Migrations have worked in the past. Below are the migrations in solution explorer compared with those found in the `__MigrationHistory` table in the database.

http://content.screencast.com/users/Chevex/folders/Snagit/media/7abeaa46-ff0f-4817-a0d7-1adb086e8f0c/03.21.2013-10.30.png

http://content.screencast.com/users/Chevex/folders/Snagit/media/3c6ac54d-f63d-417f-9253-39b6a8fea85d/03.21.2013-10.32.png

It looks like I should be able to run `update-database` and have it tell me that it is up to date, but I get that error instead.

As I understand it, migrations shouldn't be paying any attention to our two website projects when I'm running migrations commands, but I poured over their Web.config files as well just in case. The connection strings are identical to App.config.

#### Edit:

I've even tried completely uninstalling and removing the EF 5 package from the projects and reinstalling. Same issue >:(

Comment: You could try to grep the project for "Initial Catalog" and include all files. There must be some other connection string hidden.

Comment: Good idea @usr but it would appear there are no other places in the project where a connection string can be found. I searched for various different pieces of the string to be sure. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I had major issues with connection errors when I first switched to EF5 Code First - if I supplied a username and password, no matter what permissions I gave it would simply fail to log in from the EF side when making modifications to the schema.  I switched to trusted credentials and the issue went away, so I didnt really solve it in a way which would help you - but I shall be watching this post very closely!

Comment: @moo hopefully my answer helps you a little bit? Maybe changing your connection string didn't actually help at all. Maybe you just happened to also change your startup project?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Did your start project contains web.config or app.config as EF use the start project as source of the connection string

Comment: For anyone who has also struggled with this subtlety. Vote: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/974

Comment: Thank you, I was getting frustrated with this problem.

Comment: +1000000 votes for this
I wasted an afternoon figuring this out

Comment: Though i had app.config in my startup project but that was missing connection string tag which i added and it magically worked.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so that didn't work for me at first :(

Then after a cup of coffee and adding StartUPProjectName to it, it did!
Try:

Update-Database -StartUpProjectName MYPROJECT.NAME -Script

Try to point it to a start Up project where you web.config/app.config lives

Answer (score 3):

If you get the help for enable migrations in the Package Manager Console

```
Get-Help enable-migrations -detailed
```

You can find this documentation for the -StartupProjectName option:

> -StartUpProjectName
>
> ```
>     Specifies the configuration file to use for named connection strings. If
>     omitted, the specified project's configuration file is used.
> ```

The doc it's a little confusing, but it means that if you use this option to specify a project name, migrations will look for the connection string in the config file of the specified project. (The config file can be `web.config` or `app.config`).

If you're creating a web app, most probably the connection string will be in its `web.config`, so you have to specify the web app project. If it's other kind of project, the connection string will be in an `app.config` file of a class library or whatever, and you'll have to specify that project.

Besides it's recommended that you use a constructor for your `DbContext` class that specifies the name of the connection string, i.e.

```
public class CompanyEntities : DbContext
{
    public CompanyEntities()
       :base("ConnectionStringName")
    {
         ...
    }
....
}
```

In this way you don't depend on default connection strings, which may be confusing.

Comment: Is this new? I don't remember this being there. Very nice :)

Comment: Nope! It's probably there since the first migrations release. At least since 4.3

Answer (score 1):

You say you can connect via SQL Management Studio, but my guess is you use Windows Authentication for that, and not the `uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXX;` supplied in your connection string.

Try to get Management Studio to connect using that userid and password.

Also, that account might be locked out (if it is an Active Directory account).

Comment: Nope, I connect with the [same credentials](http://content.screencast.com/users/Chevex/folders/Snagit/media/59731d5d-1b38-48ef-adaf-46d47b5d5322/03.21.2013-10.58.png). It's definitely not credentials. I've checked that many times. Also, the website projects are able to connect with the identical connection string.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm really scratching my head here lol

Answer (score 1):

This sounds eerily like a problem a client of mine had. It had to do with something having mucked up the DbProviders section of machine.config. He put the details here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/f2a19487-6d38-4a79-a809-d3efe4c9d9fe  (it's the Adam Scholz answer to his boss' question. :) )

Julie

Comment: I will check this out. I should mention we are on .NET 4.5 now in all three projects as well.

Comment: I wish I could say that was my issue, but machine.config only has one `DbProviderFactories` section defined. I checked both machine.configs in Framework and Framework64. I appreciate your response though.

Comment: ah boo (hoo hoo hoo ...had to add that so I hit the 15 char minimum! :))

Comment: oh wait...forgot to ask the MOST obvious...you do have the correct project targeted when you run the commands, right?

Comment: I do have the [right project targeted](http://screencast.com/t/P5cCyLhsBDps). However, I just accepted @Bhugot's answer above. I had a different class library set as the startup project in solution explorer. I didn't list it in the question because I thought it was irrelevant. That project had no app.config. I did not know it uses the startup project's connection string even though the migrations target was different!

Comment: yep totally related problems. Bottom line was EF was telling you "can't find the connection string because I'm looking in the wrong place" It's a TOTALLY common mistake

Answer (score 0):

May be this is solved already but i got it solved by setting the start up project in my solution to the entity dll project ( having app.config file ). I did set the "Default project" in Package Manager Console window to the correct entity dll project but that did't work. For details

[Entity Framework 6 with SQL Server 2012 gives System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583980/entity-framework-6-with-sql-server-2012-gives-)
system-data-entity-core-providerin

Answer (score 0):

If your solution has multiple projects, try setting the Startup Project for the solution to the project that contains the Web.Config or App.Config file that contains the settings for EF.

I had a solution with a Web project and seperate project (Data.Models) for my models. All was well until I added a console application to the solution. As soon as I set that to be the startup project, EF Migrations would fail.

Also, if multiple projects in the solution have migrations enabled, always run the Update-Database on each project after you do a Add-Migration. My web project had a pending migration, and the migrations failed weirdly on the second project because of the pending migration in the first.